# App Crashing on Startup Sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-3

Our app crashes seemly random on start up. About 50% of the time it works great and about 50% it crashes on start up. Can not figure out why. It only happens in iOS but works fine in Android.

**Here is the crash log.**

---

```
{"app_name":"Cordova400","timestamp":"2016-10-01 07:05:04.35 -0400","app_version":"1.2.1","slice_uuid":"f1626a60-b2a8-313a-be01-581fc53134e8","adam_id":0,"build_version":"2016.1001.1102","bundleID":"com.vitalrockDEV.app","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)","incident_id":"7CF25D79-1286-4EA5-A9DF-DD6437755214","name":"Cordova400"}
Incident Identifier: 7CF25D79-1286-4EA5-A9DF-DD6437755214
CrashReporter Key:   7d72ad7940147440a683e1c8a455707915bf7138
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Cordova400 [3905]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C541DD6B-19D1-48E6-B39E-74FD00111DE9/Cordova400.app/Cordova400
Identifier:          com.vitalrockDEV.app
Version:             2016.1001.1102 (1.2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.vitalrockDEV.app [1051]


Date/Time:           2016-10-01 07:05:04.1904 -0400
Launch Time:         2016-10-01 07:05:02.1963 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x0063393432656135
Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  1

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001877ae240 0x187775000 + 234048
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001877adf10 0x187775000 + 233232
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e99190 0x187775000 + 7487888
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e9ce88 0x187775000 + 7503496
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e9c9e4 0x187775000 + 7502308
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e9ca48 0x187775000 + 7502408
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e9c9e4 0x187775000 + 7502308
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e9ca48 0x187775000 + 7502408
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187e967c8 0x187775000 + 7477192
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187d69ca8 0x187775000 + 6245544
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001877a2a78 0x187775000 + 187000
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187a860a0 0x187775000 + 3215520
12  WebCore                         0x0000000188fb6374 0x1882e2000 + 13452148
13  WebCore                         0x0000000188fb7194 0x1882e2000 + 13455764
14  WebKitLegacy                    0x000000018943e0f0 0x1893fb000 + 274672
15  UIKit                           0x0000000189bc9540 0x189705000 + 4998464
16  Cordova400                      0x0000000100085390 0x100028000 + 381840
17  Foundation                      0x00000001843b26ec 0x1842a8000 + 1091308
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018387a278 0x18379d000 + 905848
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183879bc0 0x18379d000 + 904128
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838777c0 0x18379d000 + 894912
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837a6048 0x18379d000 + 36936
22  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185229198 0x18521d000 + 49560
23  UIKit                           0x0000000189780628 0x189705000 + 505384
24  UIKit                           0x000000018977b360 0x189705000 + 484192
25  Cordova400                      0x000000010002f430 0x100028000 + 29744
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001827885b8 0x182784000 + 17848

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x0063393432656135 0 + 27928919040942389
1   Cordova400                      0x0000000100122484 0x100028000 + 1025156
2   Cordova400                      0x0000000100126cc8 0x100028000 + 1043656
3   Cordova400                      0x000000010011a558 0x100028000 + 992600
4   Cordova400                      0x000000010011a524 0x100028000 + 992548
5   Cordova400                      0x000000010009f5fc 0x100028000 + 488956
6   Cordova400                      0x000000010009cc28 0x100028000 + 478248
7   Cordova400                      0x00000001000a7474 0x100028000 + 521332
8   Cordova400                      0x00000001000a71cc 0x100028000 + 520652
9   Cordova400                      0x00000001000a60ac 0x100028000 + 516268
10  Cordova400                      0x00000001000a10a4 0x100028000 + 495780
11  Cordova400                      0x00000001000aeee0 0x100028000 + 552672
12  Cordova400                      0x0000000100031cb8 0x100028000 + 40120
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182755200 0x182754000 + 4608
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001827551c0 0x182754000 + 4544
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182763ab4 0x182754000 + 64180
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018276538c 0x182754000 + 70540
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001827650ec 0x182754000 + 69868
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295d2c8 0x18295c000 + 4808
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb4 0x18295c000 + 3508

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb0 0x18295c000 + 3504

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFNetwork.Connection
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182899e40 0x18287b000 + 126528
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018296322c 0x18295c000 + 29228
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837a4f60 0x18379d000 + 32608
3   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840e82e8 0x183ec7000 + 2233064
4   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840e7bc8 0x183ec7000 + 2231240
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840e7a94 0x183ec7000 + 2230932
6   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840e6aa4 0x183ec7000 + 2226852
7   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183fff04c 0x183ec7000 + 1278028
8   CFNetwork                       0x000000018406c750 0x183ec7000 + 1726288
9   CFNetwork                       0x00000001840c16cc 0x183ec7000 + 2074316
10  CFNetwork                       0x00000001840c2694 0x183ec7000 + 2078356
11  CFNetwork                       0x0000000184057c7c 0x183ec7000 + 1641596
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182755200 0x182754000 + 4608
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001827551c0 0x182754000 + 4544
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182763444 0x182754000 + 62532
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001827589a8 0x182754000 + 18856
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018276538c 0x182754000 + 70540
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001827650ec 0x182754000 + 69868
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295d2c8 0x18295c000 + 4808
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb4 0x18295c000 + 3508

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018289aa88 0x18287b000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295d36c 0x18295c000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb4 0x18295c000 + 3508

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb0 0x18295c000 + 3504

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdb0 0x18295c000 + 3504

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018287c16c 0x18287b000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018287bfdc 0x18287b000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183879cec 0x18379d000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183877908 0x18379d000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837a6048 0x18379d000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001842b4b1c 0x1842a8000 + 51996
6   Foundation                      0x00000001842d560c 0x1842a8000 + 185868
7   UIKit                           0x000000018a0f5c7c 0x189705000 + 10423420
8   Foundation                      0x00000001843b250c 0x1842a8000 + 1090828
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f860 0x18295c000 + 14432
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f770 0x18295c000 + 14192
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdbc 0x18295c000 + 3516

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182899e64 0x18287b000 + 126564
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182962db4 0x18295c000 + 28084
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182962fb8 0x18295c000 + 28600
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018387797c 0x18379d000 + 895356
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837a6048 0x18379d000 + 36936
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183f93cec 0x183ec7000 + 838892
6   Foundation                      0x00000001843b250c 0x1842a8000 + 1090828
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f860 0x18295c000 + 14432
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f770 0x18295c000 + 14192
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdbc 0x18295c000 + 3516

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018289a314 0x18287b000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001827b827c 0x1827ab000 + 53884
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001822c9994 0x182282000 + 293268
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804e384 0x187775000 + 9278340
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804d484 0x187775000 + 9274500
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804d2c0 0x187775000 + 9274048
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804d160 0x187775000 + 9273696
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804e470 0x187775000 + 9278576
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804e39c 0x187775000 + 9278364
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018804e64c 0x187775000 + 9279052
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f860 0x18295c000 + 14432
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f770 0x18295c000 + 14192
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdbc 0x18295c000 + 3516

Thread 10 name:  WebThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182899e1c 0x18287b000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295e9d0 0x18295c000 + 10704
2   WebCore                         0x000000018835e5c0 0x1882e2000 + 509376
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838d0078 0x18379d000 + 1257592
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837ca59c 0x18379d000 + 185756
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000018944e31c 0x1893fb000 + 340764
6   WebCore                         0x0000000188e3a034 0x1882e2000 + 11894836
7   WebCore                         0x0000000188801da8 0x1882e2000 + 5373352
8   WebCore                         0x0000000188800cb8 0x1882e2000 + 5369016
9   WebCore                         0x00000001887fefc4 0x1882e2000 + 5361604
10  WebCore                         0x00000001887fcac0 0x1882e2000 + 5352128
11  WebCore                         0x00000001887fc448 0x1882e2000 + 5350472
12  WebCore                         0x0000000188de712c 0x1882e2000 + 11555116
13  WebCore                         0x0000000188de5884 0x1882e2000 + 11548804
14  WebCore                         0x00000001882f3bec 0x1882e2000 + 72684
15  WebCore                         0x00000001882f3b44 0x1882e2000 + 72516
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018387a8f4 0x18379d000 + 907508
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018387a608 0x18379d000 + 906760
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183879ec4 0x18379d000 + 904900
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183877ac0 0x18379d000 + 895680
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837a6048 0x18379d000 + 36936
21  WebCore                         0x0000000188347a2c 0x1882e2000 + 416300
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f860 0x18295c000 + 14432
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295f770 0x18295c000 + 14192
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018295cdbc 0x18295c000 + 3516
```

Comment: Try to make a symbolication, the log shows nothing, but that it happened in javascript